# SQL - convert query to linq to sql and to lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a sql (get all distinct MIDs with the latest Date) and I want to convert it to linq query and to lambda expression

```
  SELECT     MID, MAX(Date) AS 'Date'
  FROM         TABLE1
  WHERE     (Status = '1')
  GROUP BY MID
```

i have this lambda but I dont know how to get the MID field

```
            var result= (db.TABLE1
                       .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.MID)
                       .Select(                
                               x => x.Max(x=>x.CreatedDate)
                       )).ToList();
```

please advice how to fix the syntax for linq query and for lambda. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I dont know how to get the MID field

Use key of group to access columns which you are using for grouping. Thus you are grouping by single column, then key will be value of MID column. Then use anonymous object to select custom set of fields:

```
var result = db.TABLE1
               .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
               .GroupBy(x => x.MID)
               .Select(g => new {
                    MID = g.Key,                
                    Date = g.Max(x => x.CreatedDate)
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey works! for my knowledge if I had to groupBy by multiple fields, e.g. .GroupBy(x => new { x.MID, x.Country }) how would I specify to make MID as a key? Could you provide an example, Thank you

Comment: @Ben key will represent object which is used for grouping. If you have anonymous object with two properties, than key will be that object. Getting MID will look like `g.Key.MID`

Comment: Hi Sergey, I want to retrieve another parameter, If add in a .GroupBy and then in the .Select e.g. Name = g.Key.Name then it uses Name and MID as distinct. How do I use only MID as distinct in the GroupBy and retrieve another parameter in the .Select? Thanks again

Comment: @Ben if you would use only MID in GroupBy, then each group can (and I believe should) contain more than one entity. Each entity will have it's own Name. If you want all names, the you can use `g.Select(x => x.Name)`

Comment: I tired g.Select(x=>x.Name) and the result was System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]. I tried g.FirstOrDefault().Name and it worked hopefully it is the right way. Thanks